# Type '(newValue: DateRange<dateFns>) => void' is not assignable to type '(date: DateRange<unknown>, keyboardInputValue?: string | undefined) => void'

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I'm using the MUI date range picker (https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/) and here's what I have:

```
<StaticDateRangePickerStyled
            displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleDatePickerChange}
            renderDay={(
              date,
              dateRangePickerDayProps: DateRangePickerDayProps<dateFns>
            ) => <DateRangePickerDayStyled {...dateRangePickerDayProps} />}
            dayOfWeekFormatter={(day: string) => dayOfWeek[day]}
            components={{
              LeftArrowButton: ({ onClick }) => (
                <IconButton
                  size="md"
                  Icon={ArrowBackStyled}
                  onClick={onClick}
                />
              ),
              RightArrowButton: ({ onClick }) => (
                <IconButton
                  size="md"
                  Icon={ArrowForwardStyled}
                  onClick={onClick}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
```

and my handler is:

```
  const handleDatePickerChange = useCallback((newValue: DateRange<dateFns>) => {
    setValue(newValue)
  }, [])
```

But TypeScript is complaining:

```
Type '(newValue: DateRange<dateFns>) => void' is not assignable to type '(date: DateRange<unknown>, keyboardInputValue?: string | undefined) => void'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because the return type of the onChange function in the StaticDateRangePickerStyled component is being less than (`newValue: DateRange<dateFns>`) => `void` while the expected type is (`date: DateRange<unknown>, keyboardInputValue?: string | undefined`) => empty.

One possible solution is to explicitly set the type of onChange to (`date: DateRange<unknown>, keyboardInputValue?: string | undefined`) => void when overriding to let TypeScript automatically infer the type, like this:

```js
<StaticDateRangePickerStyled
  onChange={handleDatePickerChange as (date: DateRange<unknown>, keyboardInputValue?: string | undefined) => void}
/>
```